# Do I need a visa to visit Hong Kong for less than 7 days if I'm a Chinese citizen flying to and from the US?

Tags: visas, hong-kong, visa-free-entry, chinese-citizens

I am a Chinese citizen (US permanent resident) planning on going to Hong Kong for 7 days, flying to and from Chicago, and originally had found this stipulation:

> Chinese passport holders who are in transit through Hong Kong from
>   another country, region or territory may be granted a stay of 7 days
>   without the prior need to obtain an entry permit, with the condition
>   of possession of valid Chinese passport and confirmed onward air
>   tickets for the overseas journey. If Chinese passport holders will go
>   for mainland China or Macau via Hong Kong, onward air tickets are not
>   compulsory.

Seeing this, I assumed I would need a visa because I am not going to a third country, and hence would not be considered transit. However, after sending in my visa application to a travel agency, they sent it back saying it was returned by the Chinese consulate who claimed I do not need it if staying for 7 days or less. I am a little skeptical because of previous questions here that indicated I would need it for entry, and that I don't have anything in writing for the actual consulate.

Does anyone here have this experience and can confirm or deny that I do NOT need a visa? And what documents do I need to bring? Just my flight back home to the US?

Comment: I just checked Timatic via [KLMs tool](https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm) and it pretty much says the same: *"Visa required, except for Passengers with a passport issued by
China (People's Rep.) in transit (including overland) to/from
a third country for a maximum stay of 7 days."* i.e. you could officially intend to go overland into China and immediately come back. But unless you actually do that "transit run" you are at least in somewhat of a gray area and I would try contacting the consulate again. +1, question shows reasearch!

Comment: From http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html: "2. PRC passport holders living overseas wishing to enter Hong Kong for visit, employment, training, study or residence should apply for an appropriate entry permit." (Paragraph 3 notes the 7-day exemption for travelers in transit.) "4. PRC passport holders should apply for an entry permit for social and business visits to Hong Kong."  This confirms @mts's Timatic findings and the resulting advice to double-check with the consulate.  When you do so, stress that you will not be in transit.

Comment: I suspect the travel agent is correct that you don't need a HK permit for a 7 day stay. Chinese nationals from the mainland are always allowed to stay in Hong Kong for a 7 day visit without a HK permit, but are only allowed to use a passport to enter Hong Kong for their 7 days if they are arriving from somewhere or have onward travel requiring the passport (hence "transit"). Otherwise they can still enter Hong Kong from the mainland for 7 days, but must use a different type of travel document issued by the mainland. In your case I think the passport is perfectly okay, but I can't prove this.

Comment: The answer of Dennis is not correct. Chinese mainland citizens from mainland also need HK visa on the special travel document. You Do need a visa if you just arrive and return to US. Sure you can take a train trip to Shenzhen and then return to HK, and you will have 14 days in total. Maybe you'd better to take spend night in China and return to HK on the next day.

Comment: You can always enter HK from third countries, but if you do not finish the transit (the exit control officer will check you destination), you have the chances to be fined and banned for further travel to HK by leaving a "D.T." stamp on you passport.

Comment: Macau is also an option. But Chinese can only enter Macau without visa in transit, which means HK-MO-HK will break the Macau laws.

Comment: @ShuangLiu, An endorsement is required for the China 2-way permit, but it is hard to call this a "Hong Kong visa" since it is obtained from China rather than HK and is enforced (at Lo Wu) by China exit immigration. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit-Entry_Permit_for_Travelling_to_and_from_Hong_Kong_and_Macau) matches my understanding. I'm also having trouble believing HK immigration cares to match your departing flight to your arriving flight to determine it's not a transit, but I guess that's possible. I still lean to believing what the consulate apparently said.

Comment: @Dennis All application of the endorsement type other than Tourism with be forwarded to HK immigration department. It is just called another name, but works like visa.

Comment: @ShuangLiu, Not to belabor but that's my point. Plain old 7 day tourist visits from China don't require advance permission from HK IMD. Plain old 7 day tourist visits on a PRC passport don't either. I think the "transit" aspect of the latter is only that China->HK->China visits can't be done with the passport. I could be wrong but my way is consistent with the consulate's refusal to issue a HK visa for a 7 day trip from overseas.

Comment: "Holders of People's Republic of China (PRC) passports PRC passport holders living overseas wishing to enter Hong Kong for visit, employment, training, study or residence should apply for an appropriate entry permit. Please refer to paragraphs 18-22 for application procedures." Notice here also include "visit". If fly from overseas means transit, this regulation makes no sense then.

Comment: @ShuangLiu, visits longer than 7 days require prior HK IMD approval (i.e. a visa), like longer stay 'T' and 'Q' endorsements on the 2-way permit require prior HK IMD approval. No one needs 7 days to transit HK, you can get from one end to the other in a couple of hours, so the 7 days you get is for a visa-free visit. A longer visit requires a visa. I see no inconsistency.

Comment: IMNAL, but I never seen any official announcement that overseas Chinese are entitled a 7-day visa-free trip. Please correct me if there is any.

Comment: And no one needs 30 days transit in Seoul, South Korea. But if Chinese wish to enter S. Korea visa-free, the transit must be done by flying from/to the designated countries.